# C# - Appending text files

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have code that reads a file and then converts it to a string, the string is then written to a new file, although could someone demonstrate how to append this string to the destination file (rather than overwriting it)

```
private static void Ignore()
{
    System.IO.StreamReader myFile =
       new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
    string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();

    myFile.Close();
    Console.WriteLine(myString);

    // Write the string to a file.
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test2.txt");
    file.WriteLine(myString);

    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: Trying something like:    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("log.txt"))
        {
            Log("Test1", w);
            Log("Test2", w);
            // Close the writer and underlying file.
            w.Close();
        }

Comment: You might consider picking up [C# 3.0 Cookbook](http://www.amazon.com/C-3-0-Cookbook-Jay-Hilyard/dp/059651610X/) or [C# 4.0 in a Nutshell](http://www.amazon.com/C-4-0-Nutshell-Definitive-Reference/dp/0596800959/) - they cover a lot of the basics.

Comment: And look in to [using blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: @TrueWill Thanks, ill look for soom online versions, don't fancy paying that much for a book

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the file is small, you can read and write in two code lines.

```
var myString = File.ReadAllText("c:\\test.txt");
File.AppendAllText("c:\\test2.txt", myString);
```

If the file is huge, you can read and write line-by-line:

```
using (var source = new StreamReader("c:\\test.txt"))
using (var destination = File.AppendText("c:\\test2.txt"))
{
    var line = source.ReadLine();
    destination.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: thanks helped me out alot, amazing how much more compact yours is as well

Answer (score 9):

```
using(StreamWriter file = File.AppendText(@"c:\test2.txt"))
{
    file.WriteLine(myString);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx)

```
File.AppendAllText("c:\\test2.txt", myString)
```

Also to read it, you can use [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) to read it. Otherwise use a `using` statement to Dispose of the stream once you're done with the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("C:\\test.txt");
writer.WriteLine(mystring);
```